# Flatlist - Set height and scroll

Tags: scroll, react-native-flatlist

I need help in setting correctly a Flatlist in my React Native app.

What I need is:

- I have a View
- Inside that view i have a title on top and a bottom below.
- Between I want to insert a Flatlist that displays a list of elements, but i want a fixed height and scroll capability to see all elements from the list.

Part of my code:

```js
return (
    <Container theme={theme}>
      <TitleContainer theme={theme}>
        <Title theme={theme}>Destino da publicação:</Title>
      </TitleContainer>
      <ButtonContainer>
        <Option theme={theme} onPress={() => setView('contacts')}>
          <Texto theme={theme}>Contactos</Texto>
        </Option>
        <Option theme={theme} onPress={() => setView('groups')}>
          <Texto theme={theme}>Grupos</Texto>
        </Option>
      </ButtonContainer>
      <ContactContainer>
        {view === 'contacts' && (
          <FlatList
            key="contactList"
            data={contactListFiltered}
            renderItem={renderItemContact}
            ListEmptyComponent={() => (
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: `${theme.mainColor}`,
                  textAlign: 'center',
                  fontSize: VMHSize(811, 14),
                }}
              >
                Sem contatos
              </Text>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.email}
          />
        )}
        {view === 'groups' && (
          <FlatList
            key="groupListShare"
            data={groupListFiltered}
            renderItem={renderItemGroup}
            ListEmptyComponent={() => (
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: `${theme.mainColor}`,
                  textAlign: 'center',
                  fontSize: VMHSize(811, 14),
                }}
              >
                Não existem grupos criados
              </Text>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item}
          />
        )}
        <ButtonContainer>
          <Option onPress={close} theme={theme}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="cancel"
              size={VMHSize(811, 25)}
              color={theme.mainColor}
            />
            <OptionText theme={theme}>Cancelar</OptionText>
          </Option>
        </ButtonContainer>
      </ContactContainer>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

I already tried many suggestions I readed, but or the flatlist appears with the height I want but i cant scroll the content, or the flatlist renders all elements pushing the bellow content of the view to outside the view.

**To explain the idea if the code:**

I´m building a social media app, something alike facebook. I have a view **Posts**, where i have a *flatlist* that displays the posts from the feed for the user.

Then, each post have a **Options** button with many options, one is to share the post with another friend. In the code above, i need to show in a view with a fixed height, a list with the friends. If i have many friends, i need to scroll that list within the limited size view. I´m using another flatlist to list the friends.

Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Well, I resolved my problem with a **ScrollView** and **nestedScrollEnabled** prop.

```js
<ScrollView style={{ height: VMHSize(811, 300) }} nestedScrollEnabled>
        {view === 'contacts' && (
          <FlatList
            key="contactList"
            data={contactListFiltered}
            renderItem={renderItemContact}
            ListEmptyComponent={() => (
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: `${theme.mainColor}`,
                  textAlign: 'center',
                  fontSize: VMHSize(811, 14),
                }}
              >
                Sem contatos
              </Text>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.email}
          />
        )}
        {view === 'groups' && (
          <FlatList
            key="groupListShare"
            data={groupListFiltered}
            renderItem={renderItemGroup}
            ListEmptyComponent={() => (
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: `${theme.mainColor}`,
                  textAlign: 'center',
                  fontSize: VMHSize(811, 14),
                }}
              >
                Não existem grupos criados
              </Text>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
          />
        )}
      </ScrollView>
```

Comment: FlastList should not be rendered inside ScrollView